# JQuery always loads before AngularJS document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using **AngularJS** to display results of my API (my first attempt at AngularJS), and want to use **Jquery** to add some effects to the page. 
The problem is, Jquery seems to load before Angular has time to add images and other elements to the page. 
 This prevents the **JQuery** effects from working I have been through numerous answers and tutorials, which center around the following solutions, none of which have worked for me.

Another approach suggested was to put the **JQuery** into "directives", but how would I put the contents of 3 large javascript libraries into an **AngularJS** directive? Sorry, I'm new in **Javascript**!

Here are the unsuccessful attempts:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
 // load JQuery plugins 
 $.getScript("./js/plugins.all.min.js");
});

<!-- after Angular is loaded !-->
  angular.element(document).ready(function ()  {  
     // load JQuery plugins 
 $.getScript("./js/plugins.all.min.js");
});

 <!-- after Jquery-main is loaded !-->
$(document).ready(function() {  
 // load JQuery plugins 
 $.getScript("./js/plugins.all.min.js");
});
```

Here are the relevant extracts of my code:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyWebpage</title>


    <!-- Template includes !-->
    <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/slider-revolution.css">
      <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/all.css">
      <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" class="color">
</head>

<body ng-app=“myApp">

        <div ui-view></div>

</body>

<!-- Application Dependencies -->
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/build/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!-- Template scripts !-->

<!-- Application Scripts -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/indexController.js"></script>
```

app.js :

```
  ...
state('index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '../views/indexView.html',
                controller: 'IndexController as user'

...
```

indexView.js

```
...
<!— JQuery plugin gallery -->

    <div class="gallery responsive">
        <div class="mask" ng-if=“myStuff.banner">
            <ul class="slideset">
        <ul style="margin:0px; padding:0px">
                <li class="slide" data-transition="slidedown" data-slotamount="10" data-masterspeed="300" data-thumb="" ng-repeat="banner in user.banner" width="300">

                     <! -- load a big ol’ picture !—> 
                    <img ng-src="../../storage/img/{{banner.image.image_url}}">

                    <div class="caption text-box lfl lfl" data-x="-91" data-y="140" data-speed="300" data-start="800" data-easing="easeOutExpo">
                        <h1><span>{{banner.banner_title}}</span></h1>
                        <a class="more" href="{{banner.banner_link}}">READ MORE</a>
                        <div style="" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows default"></div>
                        <div style="" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows default"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

...

indexController.js:

```
...
// gets all the data from my API, including image src 
vm.getMyStuff = function() {           
$http.get('http://localhost:8888/api/public/myapistuff).success(function(myStuff) {
            vm.myStuff = myStuff;
        }).error(function(error) {
            vm.error = error;
        });
    }
}

})();

$(window).load(function() {

 // load JQuery plugins 
 $.getScript("./js/plugins.all.min.js");

});
```

Comment: controllers are loaded before the angular tags and stuff is rendered - basically they're control logic.  You're looking for a directive's 'link' function, which is roughly the same idea as 'load()', or possibly '.run()' which is a property of angular, and can be appended to the 'module()' app definition which you probably have in app.js

Comment: You can't really just load a large javascript file into an angular directive. It usually has to be rewritten as directives for angular. For example, [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and [Angular Foundation](https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) provide directives for Bootstrap and Foundation (respectively). It's not a simple task.

Comment: Could you elaborate about how I might use the directive link function?

Comment: Does your jQuery file actually add effects on its own? Or is it more of a plugin providing methods that you call? You could try to just load the plugin before Angular, then write directives which use the plugin.

Comment: As soon as the JQuery files load they apply their settings to elements. They are templates designed to do exactly that.